# запрос без использования перебора записей

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Доброго времени суток. Суть вопроса такая.
Имеется таблица вида:

```
id   kol  num
290   1   32
290   5   33
300   2   34
```

Возможно ли построить запрос без использования цикла(курсора и тд) чтобы вывести данные такого вида:

```
id     res
290   32-1, 33-5
300   34-2
```

Сильно не пинайте, заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: если у ms'а есть аналог `STRING_AGG` или `GROUP_CONCAT`, то как-то так: `SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(kol,' ',num) SEPARATOR ', ') AS res`

Comment: @Fat-Zer *если у ms'а есть аналог STRING_AGG* Есть, но начиная с MS SQL 2017...

Comment: да забыл уточнить что версия 2008 ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно в MS SQL младших версий (до 2017), для конкатенации строк используют такой подход:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (id INT, kol INT, num INT)

INSERT #test
VALUES (290, 1, 32),(290, 5, 33),(300, 2, 34)

SELECT id,
REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(
(SELECT 
CAST(num AS NVARCHAR(10))+'-'+CAST(kol AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ', ' 
FROM #test t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
FOR XML PATH(''))),1,2,'')) [res]
FROM #test t1
GROUP BY id

DROP TABLE #test
```

Но в 2017 появилась функция [STRING_AGG](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql).

Answer (score 3):

```
select id,
  res = stuff((select ',' + num + '-' + kol 
               from test 
               where id = t.id for xml path('')
              ),1,1,' ')
from test t
group by id
```

Если num и kol чисельные - добавить `CAST`.